# ClassCastException из Object в String[][] и выходящая из этого проблема с дженериками

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

`String` взят для примера.

`String[][] strings = (String[][])new Object[10]` выдаёт `ClassCastException`. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему.

В связи с этим выходит проблема с дженериками:

Есть класс для примера:

```java
class GenericClass<G> {
    G[] value;

    GenericClass(G[] value) {
        // так как создать массив из G нельзя (new G[]),
        // приходится делать массив из Object(ов)
        this.value = (G[])new Object[value.length]; // создание нового массива из обджектов всё рушит
        System.arraycopy(value, 0, this.value, 0, value.length);

        // this.value = value; работает
    }
}
```

Вот проблемный код:

```
GenericClass<String[]> genericClass = new GenericClass<>(
        new String[][] {
                new String[] {"f", "s", "t"},
                new String[] {"1", "2", "3"},
                new String[] {"п", "в", "т"}});

String[][] strings = genericClass.value; // ClassCastException (именно в этой строчке)
```

---

> Как-то же эта проблема решена в `ArrayList`. Не понимаю, как. Там вообще массив обжектов, и всё работает.

Comment: Наверное потому что `Object[]` и `String[]` это таки разные типы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы создали массив объектов, то ни к какому другому типу его привести нельзя.

Но массив дженериков всё же создать можно, когда есть откуда взять его конкретный тип. У вас оригинальный массив передаётся аргументом конструктора и этим можно воспользоваться:

```
// 1 вариант
this.value = (G[]) value.clone();

// 2 вариант
this.value = (G[]) Array.newInstance(value.getClass(), value.length);
System.arraycopy(value, 0, this.value, 0, value.length);

// 3 вариант
this.value = (G[]) Arrays.copyOf(value, value.length, value.getClass());
```

**Update:** В отношении массивов действуют те же правила приведения, что и для обычных типов - тип может быть повышен безболезненно, но приведён к типу наследника только если он реально является его экземпляром.

такое выражение корректно - создан экземпляр String[] и приведён к типу предка:

```
Object[] arr = new String[5];
```

---

не корректно - объект не является строкой и не может быть приведён:

```
String[] arr = new Object[5];
String[] arr2 = (String[]) new Object[5];
```

---

следующее корректно, создан массив строк, повышен к типу предка, потом приведён обратно к собственному типу:

```
Object[] arr = new String[5];
String[] arr2 = (String[]) arr;
```

Comment: Не понял, по идее то можно `Object` к массиву привести, он же наследует обжект. В случаях с одномерными массивами получается привести `Object[]` к `String[]`. И ещё, что делать, если передаётся не массив, а элемент массива, необходимо создать массив дженериков из пустого места.

Comment: К массиву можно привести, если он создан как массив соответствующего типа. Сделать так: `String[] strings = (String[]) new Object();` не выйдет. И так тоже: `String[] strings = (String[]) new Object[25];`. Если передаётся элемент, то их хранят в массиве объектов, и приводят к нужному типу каждый при выдаче обратно. Посмотрите исходники java-коллекций - там реализована вся эта свистопляска. Например: [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)

Comment: `this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];` то же создание массива объектов, тем не менее, в `ArrayList` можно хранить массивы.

Comment: Я сейчас поэкспериментировал, массив, приведённый к объекту, можно привести к массиву, но массив таких массивов привести нельзя. До сих пор не понимаю, почему, по идее всё логично, может быть, это недоработка явы?

Comment: Вот просто, массив же наследует `Object`, значит, по идее, я могу привести объект к массиву, а на практике - нет.

Comment: Из того, что вы сказали выходит, что массивы, содержащие одни типы нельзя привести к массивам, содержащим другие, но строчка `Object[] objects = new String[10]` корректна (даже `(Object[])` не надо писать), значит, всё-таки можно. Я говорю о том, что массив наследует `Object`, а значит, по идее, `Object` можно привести к `Object[]`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, подзабыл тему, ответ был несколько не верен. Смотрите апдейт. На массивы распространяются те же правила приведения, что и на обычные типы. Тип может быть повышен всегда, но понижен только тогда, когда объект на самом деле является экземпляром этого типа или его потомка.

Comment: Спасибо, я почему-то думал, что можно привести к типу повыше. Также понял, как это реализовано в `ArrayList` в методе `toArray(T[] a)`.

Answer (score 2):

Классовая переменная **G[] value** имеет тип одномерного массива, но объект инициализируется двумерным массивом **new String[][]**.

При копировании с помощью:

```
System.arraycopy(value, 0, this.value, 0, value.length);
```

тип объекта **this.value** становится Object[]String[], по этой причине происходит эксепшн **class cast Exception**

Массивы лучше копировать утилитой *Arrays*

```
this.value = Arrays.copyOf(value1, value1.length);
```